# Different execution times for matching element

Tags: r

I am a beginner in `R` and was exploring the different options available to find a matching element(position and boolean) in a vector. I got a few options to do so and I thought of seeing the execution times for each. To my surprise, despite of them doing the same thing, they were taking different times.

Can someone please throw some light on the differences.

Below is the script to find the index of matching element. Despite of `match` just finding the first index, `which` takes less time.

```
> obj<-c('a','b','c','d')
> 
> system.time( replicate(10000, match('c',obj) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.05 
> system.time( replicate(10000, which('c'==obj) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.03
```

And for returning boolean, the times are different as well.

```
> system.time( replicate(10000, is.element('c',obj) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.05 
> system.time( replicate(10000, 'c' %in% obj) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.05 
> system.time( replicate(10000, any('c'==obj) ) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02
```

Any light is much appreciated.

Comment: All these operations are so fast that you need a lot more than 10k replications to see the difference in times. Even then, timing fluctuates wide enough to say they are identical within precision

Comment: I really don't understand the reason for down vote. At least people should care to give explanation. There are two ways to get ahead. Either score high or down vote others

Answer (score 8):

`match` needs to build a hash table which is a costly operation and worth only when searching for a match in many elements. `%in%` is a wrapper around `match`.

`which(x == y)` loops over the vector twice (one to test for equality and one to return the index of the `TRUE`. `any(x == y)` behaves like `which` but stops looping once a `TRUE` is found.

`match` returns only the first match while `which` returns all matches.

You can compare the performance regarding the number of elements to search for a match with something like:

```
n = seq_len(1e2)
tab = seq_len(1e5)

ans = lapply(n, function(n) {
                  x = seq_len(n)
                  summary(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(match = match(x, tab),
                                                         which = unlist(lapply(x, function(X) which(X == tab))),
                                                         'in' = x %in% tab, 
                                                         any = unlist(lapply(x, function(X)any(X == tab))),
                                                         unit = "ms",
                                                         times = 15))$median
                })

plot(NULL, xlim = c(1, length(ans)), ylim = range(unlist(ans)))
lines(sapply(ans, "[[", 1), col = "red")
lines(sapply(ans, "[[", 2), col = "blue")
lines(sapply(ans, "[[", 3), col = "pink")
lines(sapply(ans, "[[", 4), col = "lightblue")
legend("topleft", fill = c("red", "blue", "pink", "lightblue"), legend = c("match", "which", "in", "any"))
```

[image]

***Edit*** May 4 '16:

In R >= 3.3.0, when `x` in `match(x, table)` is of `length(x) == 1L`, a simple linear search is made until the first match is found and the overhead of `match`'s setup is avoided:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no "definite" answer for the reason why those functions differ in efficiency. In general, two functions that provide the same output need not be equally efficient. On the other hand, the observable difference in efficiency often depends on the input (size, format) and the way you use a function.

In your example, `is.element` and `%in%` are actually identical because they both simply call `match` for what they do. See `?is.element` and `?match` for a description and `is.element` (without parentheses in an R console) for what the function does.

The third function (`any`) is a primitive function. Such functions can often be very efficient, because they execute C routines directly. The way in which primitive functions are handled differs from "regular" functions in R.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [microbenchmark](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html) and see which one is more efficient:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(match('c',obj),which('c'==obj),is.element('c',obj) , 'c' %in% obj,any('c'==obj),times =10000)
Unit: nanoseconds
                 expr min   lq      mean median   uq     max neval cld
      match("c", obj) 489  978 1126.1920    979  980 1209606 10000  b 
    which("c" == obj) 489  978 1036.7159    979  980   31770 10000  b 
 is.element("c", obj) 978 1467 1810.8117   1468 1956 1150469 10000   c
         "c" %in% obj 978 1468 1826.2425   1469 1957   27860 10000   c
      any("c" == obj)   0    2  355.7135    490  491   23461 10000 a
```

## with 1 million times

```
microbenchmark(match('c',obj),which('c'==obj),is.element('c',obj) , 'c' %in% obj,any('c'==obj),times =1000000)
Unit: nanoseconds
                 expr min   lq      mean median   uq      max neval  cld
      match("c", obj) 489  978  995.9749    979  980  4391720 1e+06  b  
    which("c" == obj) 489  978 1013.2343    979  980  1193478 1e+06  b  
 is.element("c", obj) 978 1467 1663.1172   1468 1956  1202763 1e+06   c 
         "c" %in% obj 978 1468 1869.0499   1469 1957 56815228 1e+06    d
      any("c" == obj)   0    2  348.8258    490  491  1186147 1e+06 a
```